# What resources in Forgotten Realms describe 'official' holidays?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms

What books describe holidays within the Forgotten Realms? I know in Greyhawk, there is a Harvest Day for example.

In the USA we have holidays like New Year's, Memorial Day, Thanksgiving and Christmas. Where can I find out what the Forgotten Realms have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main book, *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*, gives the canonical holidays on page 77, under the heading "The Calendar of Harptos" in the "Time and Seasons" section.

Comment: Is that the only book?

Comment: @Ruut Every core FR setting published has listed the same set of holidays, since they're an integral part of how the calendar works.

Comment: Absolutely. Now my friend will read this answer and owe me a pizza.

Comment: @Ruut Consider adding the terms of the bet to the question. Even if you don't, I'm interested: Did you're friend believe the over-30-year-old fantasy setting had no holidays or what?

Comment: @Ruut Depending on the wording of the bet, that pizza might not be owed yet. What is the point of contention?

Comment: I am away from all of my books at the moment and am playing via Skype. I am having a character "plan for the holidays" for a money making scheme. My friend who is DM'ing asked, "What holidays are in D&D?" I said I didn't know off the top of my head but I was sure there was. He said, "Well, there will be a pizza here waiting for you if you can show me where there are official holidays in Forgotten Realms."

Comment: @Zachiel Yes. Those are "holy days" as opposed to "holidays" and not observed by everyone though (most aren't "a day off" anyway), so they aren't similar to the Federal holidays mentioned in the OP and I didn't mention them.